# jQuery custom validation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing a custom validation to compare if two phone numbers are equal or not, the code can be seen working at jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tNacL/1/). The issue is that it is not validating although I entered an equal phone number, can anyone help me out?

Comment: Can you point to the documentation that describes using the form id itself as a validation target? I searched, but couldn't find it--I had to add the custom method to each of the fields before it worked for me.

Comment: I haven't found that as well.. I assume that it should work. Otherwise I just wanted to have this validation working

Comment: I guess I'm not sure why you would assume that w/o any supporting documentation--I didn't see that in any of the examples or docs. In any case, it works when added to each element.

Comment: not sure that I understand you correctly but you're saying that the validation is fine, it's just the validation target that is an issue?

Comment: Like I said, if I add the method to each field, it works fine. I couldn't find any support for what you were trying in the demos, examples, docs, or code.

Comment: okay, so the code in the validation is not an issue then, the issue is where I place the validation at... in this case what would be the best solution if form doesn't work? still don't understand about all the support for demos, examples, docs, code

Comment: I'm saying that what you were trying to do isn't documented anywhere, and in the plugin source I don't see why it should work. The method itself is fine; there's now much that can go wrong with it. But if nothing to calls the code, it doesn't matter if the method works or not. The "best" solution based on what? I told you one way in which it can be made to work; perhaps there are others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't validate against the form only fields. Look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/tNacL/8/